# PSD to PNG Conversion does not match

Tags: bash, imagemagick, photoshop, graphicsmagick

When converting a PSD file with a transparent background using GraphicsMagick, my PNG image is more "dull/lighter" than the source image.

I've used the following

gm mogrify -level (with countless options)
gm mogrify -modulate (with countless options)
gm mogrify -gamma (with countless options)
gm mogrify -normalize 
gm mogrify -colorspace srgb

What other options do I have in order to get the source PSD and the rendered PNG to match closely? The color is very important as they are related to product that consumers can purchase. If the color doesn't match, they may order it and not like what they receive.

Comment: What's the colorspace of your original PSD file?

Answer (score 2):

All,

I was able to successfully get the image to covert to a 1:1 match. It required me downloading the ICC profile from Adobe.

It's available here:
http://www.adobe.com/digitalimag/adobergb.html

I issued the following GraphicsMagick command:
`gm convert -profile /path/to/AdobeRGB1998.icc -compress Zip /path/for/file.psd /path/for/converted/file.tif`

Thank you all.

Comment: Well done, and thank you for sharing your new-found knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

@Jesse, are you using mogrify because you do not have Photoshop with you? If you have a PSD, the recommended method will be to use photoshop's inbuilt "save for web" or "save as PNG" option to create the PNG. Optionally, you could try using GIMP.

Comment: That would not be ideal because I am having to convert 150,000+ images.

Comment: Okay, so you could create an action and then run it over all your images as an automated process.

Comment: That is terrible slow, doesn't scale and has to be baby sat. We've done a mass conversion before using PS and it was a nightmare. Adobe has a ton of overhead. We're working directly with Adobe on this (they actually helped solve the profile issue). They informed us a lot of their customers actually use imagemagick for bath process. The only reason I opted for graphicsmagick over imagemagick is for processing speed.